# Measuring time for CSS3 to finish animations

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to compare CSS3 animations with Javascript animations, and I'm trying to measure the time it takes to complete a CSS3 animation. Using Chrome's Timeline tool, the actual time is always longer than the time that I specified in CSS3. Is there a method to automatically get the time elapsed instead of manually using the Timeline tool?

Comment: Good question. Not aware of any method. In javascript it is quite easy to do by logging the time elapsed to the console, but with CSS3 there is no output that I know of. Will be following with interest.

Comment: Have you tried using a timer and `animationEnd` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit

### In brief

**You'll have to use timestamps AFAIK.**

Depending on what you're trying to observe, you can either see the real time Javascript takes to trigger a CSS animation, or see the real time elapsed of the CSS animation.

### In details

As we've seen, `elapsedTime` is not sufficient to get the real time elapsed.

Using timestamps (`Date.now()` and `event.timeStamp`), I determined the real time elapsed for the animation & the time elapsed between animation trigger and `animationEnd` event:

- Save current timestamp when adding the animating class in Javascript,
- Save the timestamp in `animationStart`,
- Save the timestamp in `animationEnd`,
- Compare those timestamp.

Here is the result of my tests on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab95Y/3/):

[image: Debugger Timeline]

```
console.log('Time elapsed between animation trigger and AnimationEnd : ' + (animationEndTimestamp - animationTriggeredTimestamp) + 'ms');
console.log('Time Animation took really ' + (animationEndTimestamp - animationStartTimestamp) + 'ms');
```

We can see that javascript takes ± 4.3 seconds to recalculate the style, and then the animationStart event is triggered. The former takes exactly 2874ms to recalculate and layout. **So that match the timeline, no need for it anymore**.

*Note: I've run this test with 10, 100, 1000, 10000 & 20000 divs.*

---

## Old answer

Interesting question!

You could use a listener for CSS3's ended animation event, called `animationend` (vendor-prefixes applies) :

```
yourElement.addEventListener("animationend", animationListener, false);
```

And then use one of `AnimationEvent`'s properties, `elapsedTime` :

> #### AnimationEvent.elapsedTime (Read only)
>
> Is a float giving the amount of
>   time the animation has been running, in seconds, when this event fired, excluding any time the animation was paused.
>
> For an `animationstart` event, `elapsedTime` is `0.0` unless there was a negative
>   value for `animation-delay`, in which case the event will be fired with
>   `elapsedTime` containing  `(-1 * delay)`.

References :

- [AnimationEvent on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent),
- [The article I stumbled upon](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/),
- and [here for an example](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/animation-api/index.html).
- Current vendor prefixes :

  - `animationend`
  - `webkitAnimationEnd`
  - `MSAnimationEnd`
  - `oAnimationEnd`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this out, but it always produces the time for the animation property. I tried animating 10000 div's with `animation:mykeyframes 2s`. The animation took about 10 seconds, but AnimationEvent.elapsedTime said it was exactly 2 seconds :/

Comment: @Linksku It would have been too easy… Could you provide me a fiddle of your test? I'd like to run some experiments too!

Comment: Here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/Ab95Y/ The delay is so that you can use Chrome's Timeline tool to measure it manually.

Comment: @Linksku Made my tests, see my edited answer: timestamps are the only sure way AFAIK.